# What does the Qur'an say about freedom of speech?

Tags: sharia, quran

What does the Qur'an say about freedom of speech? What are the verses of the Qur'an that talk about freedom of speech?

Comment: Maybe a better formulation is what Verses of the Quran could be understood as a motivation for freedom of speech ... I think I've read a book or article about human rights in shari'a...

Comment: I'm sad to say that my findings so far where useless as they only quoted the topic as a side note :(

Answer (score -1):

Devoted Muslim can't use freedom of speech to insult others... 
( Verse 11 )
يٌا أَيُّهٌا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لاٌ يَسْخَرْ قَومٌ مِّنْ قَوْمٍ عَسَى أَنْ يَكُونُوا خَيْراً مِّنْهُمْ وَلاٌ نِسٌاءٌ مِّنْ نِّسٌاءٍ عَسَى أَنْ يَكُنَّ خَيْراً مِّنْهُنَّ وَلاٌ تَلْمِزُوا أَنفُسَكُمْ وَلاٌ تَنٌابَزُوا بِالأَلْقٌابِ بِئْسَ الإِسْمُ الْفُسُـوقُ بَعْدَ الإِيـمٌانِ وَمَنْ لَّمْ يَتُبْ فَأُوْلٌئِكَ هُمُ الظٌّالِمُونَ
“O’ you who have true faith! Do not let men make fun of other men – perhaps they may be better than the other (group of men). Also, do not let women make fun of other women, as it may be that they are better than the other (group of) women. Do not find faults in yourselves and do not defame one another by using bad names. How bad it is after having true faith that a person (does these acts) but does not turn in repentance (to Allah) so then surely it is these people who are the oppressors.”
But there is not legal punishment on freespeech.... 
And if a non Muslim tried to practice hatespeech on islam... 
Muslim should leave him alone and ignore him